# Accessing Time Capsule Drive from SSH?

Tags: ssh, permissions, osx

I have an Apple Airport Extreme Time Capsule. I'd like to use it to store information for data mining operations.

I've set up OS X server, and set up user accounts such that users can log into a Mac Mini through SSH. Ideally, I'd like to mine data and store it in the time capsule, which is located at `/Volumes/Data` (the time capsule is named `Data`). Currently, it is assigned to the `wheel` group. Users can go to that directory by accessing `super su` but I don't want to be running twitter mining scripts as super-user, nor do I want my team-mates running scripts as super-user.

Is there any clean permissions fix to this? I've tried `chmod`, but I get a permission denied error.

Comment: If you get no responses here, you might get more answers at https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by taking it a completely different route:

I had the Linux machines that were trying to connect to the machine VPN into the network by generating a PPTP config, and then I edited their `fstab` configuration files to add this statement:

```
//10.0.1.1/Data /mnt/timecapsule  cifs    password=<timecap pw>,uid=1000,sec=ntlm,user    0 0
```

Where the `10.0.1.1` IP is the local IP of the time capsule, `Data` is the folder I'm mounting (the default folder name on the time-capsule is `Data` -- if you are reading this in the future, it may change), and `<timecap pw>` is the time-capsule password.